# Output EventEmitter is always undefined

Tags: angular

I've got a component which needs to emit a value but I cannot for the love of god figure out why the `@Output()` is always `undefined` when I call it. I have the exact same code in other components and trigger it the same way but it just does not want to work in this case.

Is there anything wrong I'm doing here?

```
export class DropdownOptionsSingleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() current: any;
  @Output('currentChange') onCurrentChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  private isOpen: boolean = false;

  constructor(private _globals: GlobalVariablesService, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.ns = _globals.ns;

    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

      // If the clicked element is not the component element or any of its children, close the dropdown
      if (_elementRef.nativeElement !== e.target && !_elementRef.nativeElement.contains(e.target)) {
        this.isOpen = false;
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let list = this._elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName(this.ns + '-dos-list')[0];
    let options = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (let option of options) {
      option.addEventListener('click', this.select);
    }
  }

  toggle() {

    if (this.disabled) {
      this.isOpen = false;

      return false;
    }

    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

  close() {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

  select(e) {
    this.current = e.target.getAttribute('data-model');

    // Error saying this.onCurrentChange is undefined...
    this.onCurrentChange.emit(this.current);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you call the `select` method from the template?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I don't, I have to bind the function to the list elements using `option.addEventListener('click', this.select);` since the list elements are transcluded into the component.

Comment: Oh I see. That's the cause of your problem ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you reference a method so you lose the execution context. Using the following instead:

```
option.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  this.select(event);
});
```

Or the `bind` method:

```
option.addEventListener('click', this.select.bind(this));
```

But there are drawbacks to use the `bind` method with TypeScript:

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html

Comment: Well mister, turns out you were right. Should've thought of that myself :D Thanks!